# javascript unexpected identifier on simple chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm following along to a tutorial to build chrome extensions and for some reason, my code gives me errors even though it is identical to what I see.

```
var contextMenuItem = {
    "id": "hideElement",
    "title":  "Hide Element",
    "contexts": ["selection"]
};

chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickData) {
    if (clickData.menuItemId == "hideElement" && clickData.selectionText) {
        clickData.selectionText.hide();
    }
});
```

I get an error `Unexpected identifier` here `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickData) {`

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: The posted code *seems* correct. The problem is probably elsewhere. Try removing portions of the file until it works so you'll know what's wrong.

Comment: Er, wait, there's no such method `hide()` on a [string value clickData.selectionText](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked).

Comment: That was the issue! Thanks. I replaced that line with a simple `console.log` and it worked.